# rWishart function not found in R

Tags: r

I am using R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08) on Windows 7 and wish to use the function `rWishart`.

When I enter, say, `rWishart(1,2,3)`, I get

```
Error: could not find function "rWishart"
```

Entering just `rWishart`, however, displays a matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
```

To check that this object is not interfering with the function, I did `rm(rWishart)`, and now `rWishart` gives

```
Error: object 'rWishart' not found"
```

but I still get the function-not-found error when using it as a function.

A search of my hard drive finds no rWishart.* file. I Googled and downloaded an rWishart.R file from 
https://projects.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/cxxr/svn/branches/sqlite/src/library/stats/R/ 
to the directory shown by getwd().

When I did load("<DIRECTORY>/rWishart.R") , I got

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file 'rWishart.R' has magic number '#  Fi'
   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Would someone be able to tell me how I can get the `rWishart` function running?

Answer (score 2):

rWishart wasn't introduced in base R until 2.15.  So you should update your version of R or find a package that adds the functionality.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the easiest way to find when a function was added?

Comment: This is one place to look: https://github.com/wch/r-source/commits/fbf5cdf29d923395b537a9893f46af1aa75e38f3/src/library/stats/src/rWishart.c

Comment: @RichardScriven I'd suggest that you ask that as a question but as it is it would end up being a duplicate ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111420/figure-out-what-version-of-r-a-function-was-introduced-in

Comment: Ah, very nice.  `news` is news (to me).