# Is there a function to know when a function was released?

Tags: r

When developing a package, it's useful to know when a function that we want to use was introduced in R or in a dependency, so that we know whether including it will change the dependencies of our package. Is there a function that takes a function name as input and outputs the R version or the package version in which it was released?

Example:

```r
implemented_in("list2DF()")
#> '4.0.0'
```

Even better if this function could work for every package and not just for base R, for example:

```r
implemented_in("dplyr::relocate()")
#> '1.0.0'
```

Comment: For current package installation only: `"relocate" %in% ls("package:dplyr")`, you might test if needed functions exist.

Comment: You might be able to construct something based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111420/figure-out-what-version-of-r-a-function-was-introduced-in

Comment: @Clemsang yes but if I want to know if a function exists, I can easily know it with the docs or Rstudio autocomplete. I wish there's something as fast to know in which version a particular function was implemented

Comment: @harre Thanks! It's not perfect because it shows every time a function was mentioned in the news (+ it won't work for packages), but I'll dig more

Comment: Agreed. However, you can use it for some packages, e.g. `news(package = "dplyr")`

Comment: It would not be fast or convenient **at all** but you could scrape your way through the CRAN archives for a package, construct lists of functions, etc etc etc etc.. Not "existing function" though

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the info, I'm working on a package to easily display all the info on a particular function that are put in the changelog. Not what I wanted first but it'll make it easier to find when a function appears and when it changes. I'll put a link here when it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there's a package for that: [`apicheck`](https://github.com/hughjonesd/apicheck). It's slower than printing the news, but probably more robust and tested (and it has much more functionalities as well):

```r
library(apicheck) # hughjonesd/apicheck

when_fun_exists("base::list2DF", report = "brief")
#> [1] "4.0.0"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I made a small package for this. It doesn't extract the version in which a function was introduced but it gets all mentions of a function in the NEWS. Therefore, you can find when a function was added, but also when it was modified:

```r
library(getnews)

getnews("paste0")
#> VERSION 2.15.0 
#>  =========== 
#> 
#>  New function paste0(), an efficient version of paste(*,
#> sep=""), to be used in many places for more concise (and
#> slightly more efficient) code. 
#> 
#> 
#> VERSION 4.0.1 
#>  =========== 
#> 
#>  paste() and paste0() gain a new optional argument recycle0.
#> When set to true, zero-length arguments are recycled leading to
#> character(0) after the sep-concatenation, i.e., to the empty
#> string "" if collapse is a string and to the zero-length value
#> character(0) when collapse = NULL.
#> 
#> A package whose code uses this should depend on R (>= 4.0.1).

getnews("adist")
#> VERSION 2.14.0 
#>  =========== 
#> 
#>  New function adist() in package utils for computing ‘edit’
#> (generalized Levenshtein) distances between strings.

getnews("relocate", "dplyr")
#> VERSION 1.0.0 
#>  =========== 
#>  New relocate() verb makes it easy to move columns around within a
#>     data frame (#4598).
#> 
#>   
#> 
#> VERSION 1.0.3 
#>  =========== 
#>  relocate() can rename columns it relocates (#5569).
#> 
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[Link to the package](https://github.com/etiennebacher/getnews)

Answer (score 1):

You could search through the `NAMESPACE` files of package versions to find
the first time a function has been exported. Two packages help with this:
`pkgsearch` can be used to find all CRAN versions of a contributed
package, and `pacs` can retrieve and read `NAMESPACE` files.

A simple version (without handling any edge cases) of such a search function
could look like this:

```r
implemented_in <- function(fn, pkg) {
  history <- pkgsearch::cran_package_history(pkg)
  
  # Always search at least one version
  last_without <- 0
  first_with <- nrow(history) + 1
  
  # Binary search to avoid reading all NAMESPACE files
  while (first_with - last_without > 1) {
    next_index <- floor((last_without + first_with) / 2)
    
    version <- history[next_index, ]$Version
    ns <- pacs::pac_namespace(pkg, version = version)
    
    if (fn %in% ns$exports) {
      first_with <- next_index
    } else {
      last_without <- next_index
    }
  }
  
  history[first_with, ]$Version
}

implemented_in("relocate", "dplyr")
#> [1] "1.0.0"
```

However, this approach doesn't work for base R functions.